# Inter-rater reliability using two raters on the same subjects

Tags: r, dataset, agreement-statistics, cronbachs-alpha

I'm very new to R, so I'm sorry if this is a really basic question.

I'm trying to calculate interrater reliability using Cronbach's alpha for two raters using the same assessment on the same six subjects at two different periods of time.

So ideally I need interrater reliability between the two raters, and then again between the two periods of time.

The issue I'm having is how to arrange my data. I started by having a column for each assessment question (ordinal data), and then columns for Rater 1/Rater 2, the subject ID, and the assessment period etc.

[image: Original data layout]

This is the code I used:

```
columnNames = c('AG2',  'AG3',  'AG4',  'AX2',  'AX3',  'AR2',  'AR3',  'CU2',  
'CU3',  'D12',  'DO2',  'DO3',  'FM2',  'FM3',  'FR2',  'FR3',  'FR5',  'FR6',  
'CH2',  'CH3',  'GR2',  'GR3',  'IM2',  'IM3',  'PE2',  'PE3',  'AC2',  'AC3',  
'PL2',  'PL3',  'SX2',  'SX3',  'V12',  'V13')
colnames(GAPI_B) <- columnNames

columnsToReverse <- c('CU3', 'DO3', 'GR2', 'IM3', 'PE2', 'AC3')
GAPI_B[,columnsToReverse] = 6 - GAPI_B[,columnsToReverse]
alpha(GAPI_B)
```

This is the error message I get:

> NAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by
> coercionNAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercionItem = AG2
> had no variance and was deleted but still is counted in the scoreItem
> = AG3 had no variance and was deleted but still is counted in the scoreItem = AG4   had no variance and was deleted but still is counted
> in the scoreItem = AX2 had no variance and was deleted but still is
> counted in the scoreItem = AX3 had no variance and was deleted but
> still is counted in the scoreMatrix was not positive definite,
> smoothing was doneSome items were negatively correlated with the total
> scale and probably  should be reversed.   To do this, run the function
> again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' optionSome items ( AR2 AR3 DO2 DO3
> FM2 FR2 FR6 GR3 IM2 AC2 SX3 V13 NA ) were negatively correlated with
> the total scale and  probably should be reversed.   To do this, run
> the function again with the 'check.keys=TRUE' option Error in
> FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric
> variables

Does this mean that I need a separate column for each question for each subject?

[image: Second attempt at data layout (the only one that works)]

This is the only way I've got it to work, using the formula below, but it seems a bit dodgy as there are only two rows/observations (one for each rater), when in fact there are two rows/eobservations for each subject.

```
columnsToReverse <- c(Gorillas_B = 'Oumbi_CU3', 'Ozala_CU3', 'Asante_CU3',
'Lope_CU3', 'Biddy_CU3', 'Shufai_CU3' , 'Oumbi_DO3', 'Ozala_DO3', 'Asante_DO3',
'Lope_DO3', 'Biddy_DO3', 'Shufai_DO3', 'Oumbi_GR2', 'Ozala_GR2', 'Asante_GR2',
'Lope_GR2', 'Biddy_GR2', 'Shufai_GR2', 'Oumbi_IM3', 'Ozala_IM3', 'Asante_IM3', 'Lope_IM3', 'Biddy_IM3', 'Shufai_IM3', 'Oumbi_PE2', 'Ozala_PE2', 'Asante_PE2', 
'Lope_PE2', 'Biddy_PE2', 'Shufai_PE2', 'Oumbi_AC3', 'Ozala_AC3', 'Asante_AC3', 
'Lope_AC3', 'Biddy_AC3', 'Shufai_AC3')
Gorillas_B[,columnsToReverse] = 6 - Gorillas_B[,columnsToReverse]
alpha(Gorillas_B)
```

Really sorry if this is a basic question, I've tried looking for help already but haven't seen anything with two raters rating the same subjects. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A reproducible example makes it easer to see what you are doing wrong. Alpha can automatically reverse items.